# Iteration saves as multiple lists, instead of one

Tags: pandas, for-loop, iteration

I was trying several answers with for loops I found on this forum but I just cant get it done, even if it's simple ..

I am trying to save all available results into "m" but because it's a for loop, it does print all results seperatly for m.

```
for feat in main_data:
***here some kind of code irrelevant for now ***
    m = []
    stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(data1)
    if p < alpha:
        stat2, p1, dof2, expected2 = chi2_contingency(data2)
        if p < p1 or not m:
            m.append(feat)
            print(m)
```

Getting now:

```
['feat 1']
['feat 2']
['feat 3']
```

Trying to get:

```
['feat 1', 'feat 2', 'feat 3']
```

Note* I cant taget "m" out of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this lang, but seem to be redifining the array each time in the loop, pull it to a higher scope.

```
m = []
for feat in main_data:
***here some kind of code irrelevant for now ***
    
    stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(data1)
    if p < alpha:
        stat2, p1, dof2, expected2 = chi2_contingency(data2)
        if p < p1 or not m:
            m.append(feat)
            print(m)
```

Comment: True,  now I feel really dumb I couldn't get the M out of the loop :) as proposed

Comment: Just little thing, it prints 4 lists, after iteration, and I need only the last one. -1 will not work here because it's list only.

Comment: Makes sense that it prints 4 lists (or however long the loop iterates) - move the print(m) to outside of the for feat in main_data: scope